# ProgressBar while finding a file

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, progress

Hi I am trying to show a progress bar while in background the code is looping till it finds a file with specific name.

I have written following code for that but the progress bar values doesn't change.

What should I change in the code below?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();  
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        progressBar1.Visible = false;
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

        backgroundWorker1.DoWork +=
            new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged +=
            new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted +=
            new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_WorkDone);

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        progressBar1.Visible = true;
    }

    void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // Your background task goes here
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            // Report progress to 'UI' thread
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
            // Simulate long task


            while (!File.Exists(@"C:\Users\Test.txt"))
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender,
        ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // The progress percentage is a property of e
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    void backgroundWorker1_WorkDone(object sender,
        RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you see the progress bar become visible but the value doesn't change? Is the loop making more than one iteration? It seems to me like it's finding the file and thus only setting the value to zero.

Comment: there is a high chance that the `while` loop can be executed forever.

Comment: When the file gets created the control comes out of the while loop ,then also I do not see any change in progress bar.Just that it becomes invisible (the code i have written in backgroundWorker1_WorkDone)

Comment: If you want some kind of reporting when searching, you should enumerate all the files using some method and check the existence instead of using `File.Exists`.

Comment: The scenario I am working on, I am already aware of the file name as I give it an an input .Another application which takes this input takes some time to create the input file name.So I put a check on until File.Exists and wanted to show a process bar till then

Comment: The code is just broken, it hangs in the while loop and won't update progress.  This is probably induced by an attempt at showing progress but having the problem that you cannot possibly guess who long it is going to take.  That requires a time machine.

So just don't.  Set the ProgressBar's Style property to Marquee.  And don't use ReportProgress.  And don't use a BackgroundWorker either, the FileSystemWatcher class is handy to see files appearing.

Answer (score 1):

The `continue` in your code will simply continue to the next iteration of the `while(true)` loop.  It won't go back up to the `for` loop as you expect - it just keeps looping in there over and over again.   If it wasn't a background worker, it'd hang your entire program.  Since it is, it just hangs that thread.  I expect that one CPU core stays at 100% while this is running.

That being said, while the goal here is admirable, there's no good way to accomplish it.  Even if you fix the infinite loop, your progress bar will either "finish" at a low percentage (1%, 2%, 3%, done) or go up to 100, then stop updating, but without the file yet existing.